# avoid colored box in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to avoid colored box in legend? I would just like it to be `Line1` and `Line2` without the box.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=depth)) +
  geom_density(aes(color = "Line1"))+
  geom_function(fun=function(x) 
    dnorm(x, 
          mean=mean(diamonds$depth),
          sd=sd(diamonds$depth)),
    aes(color="Line2"))+
  scale_color_manual(" ", values=c(Line1="green", Line2="red"))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be acieved by adding option `show.legend = FALSE` to `geom_density`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=depth)) +
  geom_density(aes(color = "Line1"), show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_function(fun=function(x) 
    dnorm(x, 
          mean=mean(diamonds$depth),
          sd=sd(diamonds$depth)),
    aes(color="Line2"))+
  scale_color_manual(" ", values=c(Line1="green", Line2="red"))
```

[image]